# function gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()); is not working

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I have done sign in with google plus using in javascript sdk in website. it was working before two days. but now its not working because
         gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function());
is not loaded i.e not working. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
  (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();



       gapi.signin.render('customBtn', {
       'callback': 'signinCallback',
       'clientid': '<client ID>',
       'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
       'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
       'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com     /auth/userinfo.email'
       });



   function signinCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['access_token']) {
       gapi.auth.setToken(authResult);
   getEmail(); 
     } else if (authResult['error']) {
        alert('Please try again');
       // alert('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
     }
 }

    function getEmail(){
        // Load the oauth2 libraries to enable the userinfo methods.
       try
      {
          gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
         var request_mail = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
          request_mail.execute(getEmailCallback);
        });
      } 
      catch(err)
      {
            alert( "onLoadCallback error: " + err.message );
       }
     }
   function getEmailCallback(obj){
       if (obj['email']) {
     $('login:email').value = obj['email'];
     checkout.setMethod();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and an illustration of exactly what you mean by "not loaded i.e. not working"

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the specific code you are using:

```
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', 
  function(){
    console.log('loaded');
  });
```

It's possible that the script is loading successfully but something else is breaking it. Putting in the `console.log` call might help you isolate whether it's the load call that is breaking things.

Check in [the Chrome JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to see if there is an error in your JavaScript. If there is an error, e.g. `gapi is undefined`, then you should be able to better diagnose the cause for things breaking.

If you haven't already, try placing the client.load call into a callback from when the `plusone:client.js` scripts are loaded. If you are loading the scripts asynchronously, it's possible that a race condition on the script loading is preventing the Google API client for JavaScript from being able to initialize the OAuth 2.0 client. The following code will set a callback in the script so you can perform your client initilization after load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

The function `onLoadCallback` will be triggered once client.js and plusone.js have been initialized.

Comment: Hi i have created new file and did code only in html file and it works. but i implemented same code in magento checkout->onepage->login file and its not working. however there is no any script conflict. only  gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {}); function is not working. it is not showing any error or an exception.